# Using conditional class with store getters: not updating class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a `div` with a conditional class that works well when the app is loaded, but it's not updated when the store data change.

The code in my vue component looks like this

```
<span class="week-day" 
    v-bind:class="{ complete: isDayComplete(day) }" 
    v-for="day in daysInWeek" 
    v-bind:data-day="day"
>&nbsp;</span>
```

And I have `...mapGetters(['isDayComplete'])` in my `computed` object.

The `getter` looks like this

```
isDayComplete(state) {
  return (day) => {
    console.log(`called isDayComplete(${day})`)
    const formattedDay = moment(day, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    if (state.daysData[formattedDay]) {
      if (state.daysData[formattedDay].meals.length > 0) {
        console.log(`day ${day} is complete`);
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log(`day ${day} is NOT complete`);
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`no data for day ${day}`);
      return false;
    }      
  }
},
```

I update my meals data in a `mutation`

```
updateMeals(state, meals) {
  _.forEach(meals, (meal) => {
    state.daysData[meal.day].meals.push(meal);
  });
}
```

And I have an `action` that commits that mutation

```
loadMeals({ state, commit }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    get.meals.from.api()
      .then((response) => {
        commit('initDaysData');
        commit('updateMeals', response.data.data);
        return resolve();
      })
    .catch(reject);
  });
}
```

So whenever I call `loadMeals` the class is not updated if one day changes its status (complete/not-complete). If I reload the page, the class is set correctly.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common reactivity problem. You can make deep copy (use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`) to make data reactive:

```
updateMeals(state, meals) {
  _.forEach(meals, (meal) => {
    state.daysData[meal.day].meals.push(meal);
  });
  state.daysData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.daysData))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ittus answer was correct. I found another way to achieve this that maybe could
help someone else.

1. add another `mutation` on the store

   updateCompletedDays(state) {
   const newState = [];
   _.forEach(state.daysData, (currentDayData, currentDay) => {
   if (currentDayData.meals.length > 0) {
   newState.push(currentDay);
   }
   });
   state.completedDays = newState;
   },
2. commit this mutation after meals are updated
3. change `isDayComplete` getter to

   isDayComplete(state) {
   const formattedDay = moment(day, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   return state.completedDays.indexOf(formattedDay) !== -1;
   }

Basically when using reactivity going deep into arrays/object will not work, better have arrays of aggregated data (check also [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) api)